# Easy but hard Regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have some data like that in a file.

```
Start
Status:good<>
Status:bad<>
Status:dfsf<>
Status:gosdfsfod<>
Status:dogEatsCat<>
Some randomdata
End
```

<> is just end of status information
I just want to get last status. This one "dogEatsCat".

This regex is returning me all the statuses.

```
Status:(.+?)<>
```

But I just want to get the last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Alternatively, you can grab all matches and return the last match captured. This can be done [like the following](http://www.ideone.com/gteNp):

```
Regex lastRegex = new Regex(@".*Status:(.+?)<>");
MatchCollection allMatches = lastRegex.Matches(sample);
if (allMatches.Count > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine(allMatches[allMatches.Count-1].Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Then use a greedy capture before your regex:

```
.*Status:(.+?)<>
```

(You may need to swith to single-line mode such that `.` matches also newlines.)

Alternatively you can use right-to-left mode for your regex match.

A working example for both options can be found [here](http://www.ideone.com/IYzjG).

Comment: @Brad Christie do not forget the single-line and you may only use the first group, not the complete match (e.g. `lastMatch.Groups[1].Value` in your example)

Comment: @Brad Christie also in your second example you didn't switch to single-line mode (you have to add a `RegexOptions.Singleline`) or right-to-left (add a `RegexOptions.RightToLeft`)

Comment: Just emphasizing that it's nice information to have . ;-) [Working demo, btw](http://www.ideone.com/b5FTb).

Comment: @Brad Christe you can see both alternatives working [here](http://www.ideone.com/IYzjG)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the regex that you have, but only pay attention to the last match.